# Knockout.jsのカスタムバインディングでupdateが呼ばれた原因を特定したい

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

[Knockout.jsのカスタムバインディング](http://kojs.sukobuto.com/docs/custom-bindings)を作っています。

例えば`data-bind="MyBind: { value: vmCode, size: vmLength }"`のようなバインディングができるとして、`MyBind`カスタムバインディングの`update`メソッドが、`value(vmCode)`の変更によって呼ばれたのか、`size(vmLength)`の変更によって呼ばれたのか、区別したいです。

そのための手段はあるでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

単純に直前の値をどこかに記憶しておけば比較できると思います。

```
ko.bindingHandlers.MyBind={  
    update: function (element, valueAccessor) {

        // バインディングの現在の値を取得する
        var obj = ko.unwrap(valueAccessor());
        var value = ko.unwrap(obj.value);
        var size = ko.unwrap(obj.size);

        // 前回保存した値を取得する
        var p = element.__MyBindPreviousValue;

        // TODO: 現在値と前回の値を使って処理をする
        element.innerText = `${value}, ${size} <= (${p ? p.value : ''}, ${p ? p.size : ''})`;

        // 今回の値を適当な場所に保存する
        // ここでは単純にelementに値を設定している
        element.__MyBindPreviousValue = { value: value, size: size };
    } 
};
```

なお`Observable`に対しては`obj.value.subscribe(function(){})`のようにリスナーを登録することも出来ます。VM内でちょっとした処理をするのであればこれで十分ですが、質問の場合は監視対象が複合オブジェクトであるため`subscribe`で明示的に管理すると煩雑になるでしょう。